# Connect to SQL Server hosted on-prem from Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, networking, vpn

A client company has a VPN. There is a SQL Server database on the VPN.

We have an Azure App Service that needs to read and write from the SQL Server db.

Here are the options I ruled out:

- [Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) - seems like this would allow the REVERSE of what I want. Someone from a non-Azure VPN could connect to an Azure IP.
- [Express Route/MPLS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/) - this would work, but requires time-consuming physical connections to Azure, e.g. SQL Server VPN --> local Azure partner via physical cable --> Azure.

With that said, I don't know what options are left. The end goal is to quickly (and as simply as possible) to set up connections to SQL Server DBs on VPNs and Azure App Services. We have full co-operation from our clients with the SQL Server DBs, but it would be best to keep the steps simple.

I can't seem to even find a good starting point on this besides Express Route, which I have done and don't want to do again.

Is [VPN Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/vpn-gateway/) the simples/cheapest option? Since we need to do this about 50+ times, I would rather require as little set up from the client as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If they have a Site-to-Site VPN connection to Azure you can use [App Service VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#vnet-integration).  This requires setup of a S2S VPN and configuring Azure networking.

Otherwise you have to use [App Service Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections).  This requires setting up a relay agent on an on-prem server that can reach both the SQL Server and Azure.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the second option, looking into it. If no VPN Gateway is currently set up and the goal is to stand up an App Service to an on-prem VPN SQL Server connection as quickly as possible, which option would you default to?

I am reading the docs, but I haven't done this often enough to make a qualitative decision.

Comment: For a developer setting up a Hybrid Connection is usually faster since you don't need the network admins to set anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be configure site-to-site vpn connection from azure to your on-premise.

[image]

https://docs.hillstonenet.com/en/Content/Cookbook/cb29-Site-to-Site%20VPN.htm